# PyGitHub: Get private email address and Bio of the user

Tags: python, github-api, pygithub

I am trying to fetch all the information related to the user using PyGitHub.

However, when I try to get the Bio and email address of the users, it returns 'None' to most of the users.

I think this users have marked to keep private using the following setting on the GitHub:

[image]

Is there any way pssoible to fetch this email addresses usng PyGitHub or REST API.

Following is my code:

```
from github import Github
# using username and password
git = Github("access_token")

org = git.get_organization('org')
for m in org.get_members():
     i = i+1
     print(i)
     email_address = str(m.email)
     print(type(email_address))
     print('Bio:',m.bio)
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Is there anyway to avoid this stuff?

Comment: Why not use something like Gitter for communications? Or see if they can provide the email for you? Github API shouldn't give private emails to anyone, as it would be  violation of that user's privacy. If you figure out a solution it would likely be a bug and should be reported as a security issue.